# How to play protected youtube videos in mpv?

Tags: video, youtube, mpv-media-player

Mpv is not playing all video files from youtube anymore, even though youtube-dl has no problem downloading them. I've tried with streamlink+vlc and it says that the video is protected so it gave me the culprit and it is not a regional protection in question but something else I don't understand.

E.g. this clip is protected https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pdGn4r1lD0&list=PL4vbGURud_Hr1HgxK0lq6o-3sqoc0Rx6l&index=2&t=1480s

Is there some way to modify mpv.conf and configure youtube-dl to download such clips for viewing in mpv?

Comment: I cannot seem to reproduce your issue either browser or MPV plays it with no problem on my side. I played the link directly in MPV

Answer (score 2):

Because you have youtube-dl installed, a possible workaround will be to stream the output of youtube-dl to the mpv player:

```
youtube-dl -f best -o - "{youtube-video-url}" | mpv -

# with your video example:
youtube-dl -f best -o - "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pdGn4r1lD0" | mpv -
```

Comment: What do you mean? youtube-dl must be installed for streaming to  work.

Comment: Actually, pipes are not necessary. I can even resume the playlist that this video belongs to with mpv --save-position-on-quit "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4vbGURud_Hr1HgxK0lq6o-3sqoc0Rx6l" Perhaps, there's something odd in drag&drop feature that prevents playback somehow.

Answer (score -1):

you can stream directly from youtube unto mpv by grepping direct video url

```
mpv $(youtube-dl  -g  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pdGn4r1lD0 -f  '18')
```